# Pure PHP Library for Geometry Operations 7

Tags: open-source-gis, php

I am working on a php project on a shared webhost. so I am limited into mysql and php. I want to do some geometry operations in php side. In fact it is a routing algorithm which works in php. I need a library to union and intersect geometries using php. I know about GeoPHP but it needs GEOS and it is not possible to install it on shared hosts. Is there any geospatial php libraries?